# Image animation in WatchKit not working

Tags: ios, uiimage, watchkit

I'm trying to use the `UIImage.animatedImageWithImages` method to display a simple animation on the watch screen (there are a series of 35 states PNG files).

When i run the code below, which I think should work, only a static image is loaded. This is from a little test project that just has one button and one image on screen, when the button is clicked the following method runs which should load the animation, but it only loads a static image.

```
@IBAction func clicked() {

    var progressImages = [UIImage]()

    for index in 1...35 {
        let image = UIImage(named: "r\(index).png")
        progressImages.append(image!)
    }

    image.setImage(UIImage.animatedImageWithImages(progressImages,duration: 3.0))

}
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: You are using up all system memory by attempting to load all these images into memory at the same time. Do some research on how to implement animations before writing your code, there are hundreds of answers on SO that describe how to do this well.

Answer (score 0):

```
(IBAction)playAnimation {
    // Uses images in WatchKit app bundle.
    [self.animatedImage setImageNamed:@"Bus"];
    [self.animatedImage startAnimating];

    // Animate with a specific range, duration, and repeat count.
    // [self.animatedImage startAnimatingWithImagesInRange:NSMakeRange(0, 4) duration:2.0 repeatCount:3];
}

(IBAction)stopAnimation {
    [self.animatedImage stopAnimating];
}
```